# Is there a way to show progress of merge

Tags: r

I'm running the following code in R to merge two data frames to create a new one. There are two columns where the values need to match. The distance data frame is large (70 m rows) and I'm merging the data based on two columns in the `x_parents` data frame. I'm aware of the `progress_bar` function, but I think that as what I'm trying to achieve is not a loop, that won't work. As the `distance` data frame is so large, the function does take a few mins to complete but I would like to be able to show progress of the script.

```r
crosses <- merge(x_parents, distance, 
     by.x = c("Female_Parent", "Male_Parent"), 
     by.y = c("FEMALE_PARENT", "MALE_PARENT"), all.x = FALSE, all.y = FALSE)
```

Comment: Though there are various packages out there (e.g., [`progress`](https://github.com/r-lib/progress) and [`progressr`](https://github.com/HenrikBengtsson/progressr)), they both require specific intervention that `merge` is not going to allow (as you said). Many of the `dplyr` verbs do show progress; though I haven't tried a join on data that large, perhaps using `dplyr::inner_join(...)` will give you some progress indication.

Comment: Side note: it is not hard to imagine that join taking a lot of memory. Recall (or "Did you know") that simple `data.frame` objects in R will be duplicated in memory, and even though you're doing an inner-join (one of the "kindest" wrt memory use of the join varieties), it is still copying quite a bit. With data that large, I think you could consider more memory-frugal data-handling such as SQL (not in R) or `data.table` (referential semantics, avoids copy-on-write as much as possible).

Comment: Not an answer, but the equivalent tools from `dplyr` (`full_join`) or `data.table` might give you better performance than base R